# Is there a plugin for Symfony which works like phpMyAdmin?

Tags: php, symfony1

Is there a plugin for Symfony which works like phpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a component of the [sfControlPanelPlugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfControlPanelPlugin) is the closest you're going to get